# Detect the end of scrollToRow function

Tags: swift3

How can i detect the end of scrollToRow function in my tableview? i have tried to implement scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation function, however it doesn't get called when end of scrollToRow.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the delegate to your Scrollview:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{        
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    self.scrollview.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let  height = scrollView.frame.size.height
    let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
    if distanceFromBottom < height {
        print(" you reached end of the table")
    }
}
```